# PDO binding multiples strings using bindParam() and an IN() condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

The trouble I am having is that I am getting no response when I try to pass the variable binded into the query (stored in a variable `$searchString`).

The variable `$searchString = 'extreme', 'water'`

My PDO/MySQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM posts 
            INNER JOIN post_tags ON posts.id = post_tags.postid 
            INNER JOIN tags ON post_tags.tagid = tags.id 
        WHERE tags.tag IN ( :searchTags ) 
        AND posts.suspended = 0 
        GROUP BY posts.id";

$results = $db->prepare($sql);
$results->bindParam(':searchTags', $searchString);
$results->execute();
while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    echo $row[0]; // Should be the first column which is "id"
}
```

Expected output: `1` (in my database there is only one item that matches the query and its id is 1)

I suspect the bindParam() function messes with the value of `$searchString` as if I remove the bindParam() line and put the variable directly into the SQL query it works, like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN post_tags ON posts.id = post_tags.postid INNER JOIN tags ON post_tags.tagid = tags.id WHERE tags.tag IN ({$searchString}) AND posts.suspended = 0 GROUP BY posts.id";
```

**Note: the variable `$searchString` must have single quotes `'` for the SQL query to work**

Comment: Carefully read the content of `$sql` and `bindParam()` again.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast My mistake, I changed that part while adding into StackOverflow. Issue still exists with that fixed.

Comment: You'll probably get some value out of reading this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: @e_i_pi Looks to be exactly what I wanted to find. I'll have a read through now. Thanks